# auth::check in laravel 5 not working

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

I am new in laravel 5 and trying to create a simple authentication system where an user can simply registers and logs in, if the user is logged in it would show a welcome message, otherwise the registration and login buttons. But I'm trying to check whether the user is logged in using Auth::check() it's giving me false both in my controller and view though I've successfully logged in using Auth::attempt(). I've searched in SO and other sites, but found no viable solution, somewhere it said it's a bug in laravel 5, somewhere the problem was just something wrong in their code. I don't know what am I doing wrong here.

**login.blade.php**

```
@extends('master')

    @section('content')
        <h1>বাংলার পথে</h1>
        @if(Auth::check())
            <p>স্বাগতম {{ $username }}</p>
        @else
            <a class="tb-button all-around-spacing push-left" href="/login">লগ ইন</a>
            <a class="tb-button all-around-spacing push-left" href="/register">রেজিস্টার</a>
        @endif
    @stop
```

**AuthenticationController.php**

```
public function login() {
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), array(
        'user_email' => 'required|email',
        'user_password' => 'required|alphaNum'
    ));

    $niceNames = array(
        'user_email' => 'ই-মেইল',
        'user_password' => 'পাসওয়ার্ড'
    );

    $validator->setAttributeNames($niceNames);

    if($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('login')->withErrors($validator);
    } else {
        $remember = Input::get('remember');
        if(Auth::attempt(array('user_email' => Input::get('user_email'), 'password' => Input::get('user_password')), $remember)) {
            return Redirect::to('/');
        } else {
            return Redirect::to('login')->withMessage('আপনার ই-মেইল অথবা পাসওয়ার্ড টি ভূল');
        }
    }
}

public function register() {
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), array(
            'user_name' => 'required|between:6,16',
            'user_email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'user_password' => 'required|alphaNum|between:6,16|confirmed',
            'user_password_confirmation' => 'same:user_password'
        )
    );

    $niceNames = array(
        'user_name' => 'ট্রাভেলার নাম',
        'user_email' => 'ই-মেইল',
        'user_password' => 'পাসওয়ার্ড',
        'user_password_confirmation' => 'পাসওয়ার্ড নিশ্চীতকরণ'
    );

    $validator->setAttributeNames($niceNames);

    if($validator->fails()) {
        Input::flash();
        return Redirect::to('register')->withErrors($validator);
    } else {
        DB::transaction(function(){
            $user = new User();
            $user->user_name = Input::get('user_name');
            $user->user_email = Input::get('user_email');
            $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('user_password'));
            $user->save();
        });

        return Redirect::to('login');
    }
}
```

**HomeController.php**

```
public function index()
{
    if(Auth::check()) {
        $username = Auth::user()->user_name;
        return View::make('home/index')->withUsername($username);
    } else {
        return View::make('home/index');
    }

}
```

**User.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Shuvro
 * Date: 6/20/15
 * Time: 12:30 AM
 */

namespace App\models;


use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;


class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract {
    use Authenticatable;
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $fillable = ['user_name','user_email','user_password','user_password_confirmation'];
    protected $hidden = ['user_password','remember_token'];
}
```

**Routes.php**

```
Route::get('/', array('as' => 'index', 'uses' => 'HomeController@index'));

Route::get('/register', array('as' => 'register', 'uses' => 'AuthenticationController@registerView'));
Route::post('/register', array('as' => 'register', 'uses' => 'AuthenticationController@register'));

Route::get('/login', array('as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'AuthenticationController@loginView'));
Route::post('/login', array('as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'AuthenticationController@login'));
```

**CreateUserTable**

```
   Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('user_id');
        $table->string('user_name');
        $table->string('user_email')->unique('user_email');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Comment: What does the registration / seeder look like?

Comment: Have you created the users table with a migration or did you do it manually ?

Comment: in your blade files, you should check for authentication, like this: @if(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::check())

Comment: @Jazerix migration up funtion added

Comment: @Salar it didn't work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

So I was having the same issue until I visited `http://localhost/home`, after logging in.

It seems I had run `php artisan app:name NameOfApp` and it was throwing a namespace error. I changed `namespace App\Http\Controllers;` to `namespace NameOfApp\Http\Controllers;` in `HomeController.php` and it worked fine.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Put your route's in the middleware group to have access to session. like so:

```
   Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
       Route::get('/', function () {
          if(Auth::check) return "Welcome" . Auth::user()->email;

      });

   });
```

I hope this helps... (Forgive me for not using view() for when user log's in)